# How can I disable/suppress the warning I get for having SSH enabled on an ESX/ESXi host?

Tags: ssh, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter

I administer a large number of ESXi hosts, and in order to do that efficiently, I pretty much need to have SSH allowed into the hosts at all times, as it's just far too burdensome to enable and disable SSH access through vCenter/vSphere on every host every time I need to log into a host and view the CLI or SCP files between hosts, or whatever else.

However, the problem I'm facing is that the default behavior in vSphere is to display a warning icon and nag-banner on any host for which SSH access is enabled.

[image]

More than just being annoying, this makes it impossible to see from a quick visual scan if there's a warning condition I actually care about on any of my hosts, like high CPU or memory usage, or low disk space, loss of redundancy, etc.

So, how do I get rid of this warning icon (and if possible, the nag banner as well)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to change this option.

All these solutions are listed in the `VMware KB 2003637`.

About SSH, you might find useful the `esxcli` way with :

`vim-cmd hostsvc/advopt/update UserVars.SuppressShellWarning long 1`

The full documentation : [Cluster warning for ESXi Shell and SSH appear on an ESXi 5.x host](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2003637)

Comment: Wow, outstanding!  I have no idea why I had such trouble finding that KB, but thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This particular alert can be controlled in the `Advanced Settings` under the `Configuration` tab for the host in question.  Once there, go to the `UserVars` category and scroll down to `UserVars.SuppressShellWarning`.  Change the value from `0` to `1`, and you will no longer be warned that the host in question is allowing SSH access.

[image]

Comment: I see what you did here... *smile*

Comment: Credit to our favorite @ewwhite for the solution, actually, but considering what a hellacious time I had finding this in the VMware docs, I figured I'd share it for everyone else as well.

Comment: I'm alright with you getting the rep rather than @ewwhite. >smile<  (Now, if you're trailing me by less than 10K then I'd have a different opinion... >snicker<)

Answer (score 2):

In vSphere 5.5 and greater, this is easily accomplished from the vSphere Web Client interface by clicking the **Suppress Warning** link to the right of the warning text...

[image]

[image]